# How to debug a C program that produces unexpected variable values?

Tags: c

I am expecting `a` to be 5, making the comparison expression evaluate to `true` and thus print:

A = 5, B = 3, C = 6

```
main()
{

    int i,a,b=3,c=6,s;
    for(i=1;i<=1000;i++){
        if(a*a+b*b==c*c){
            printf("A = %d B = %d C = %d\n",a,b,c);
        }
        a = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? See [ask].

Comment: This is a canonical example of how not to ask.

Comment: What is this code supposed to do?  It looks like it's trying to identify a pthagorian triple.  If so, you won't find one with those values.

Comment: @dbush exactly, there are no integer solutions at all, let alone 5^2 + 3^2 == 6^2

Comment: This is just terribru.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where is a initialized? I am seeing i being set, as well as b and c, but I'm not seeing any assignment to a.

The solution is to assign the current value of i to a:  a=i prior to the if statement.  You are assigning the value after the fact.  Alternatively, evaluate i, not a.

Comment: Please try framing your answer is an helpful way. Don't question, answer..

Comment: Thank you.  I'm new to these parts.  I should probably read all the requirements before I jump in.  Thanks for the prompt.

Comment: It seems to be initialized when it says `a = i;`

Comment: @8protons, Not when the loop enters and the `if` is executed for the first time.

Comment: @TGray, You can lurk around and see how people answer, notice which ones gets criticized and which ones are liked. :)

Comment: @Haris I didn't say it was initialized in that instance. The question in this "answer" asked where it's initialized; so I said where.

Comment: @8protons, Thats a counter question actually. and `a = i;` later is not actually initialization. Once `a` is used, later assignments cannot be called initializations.

Comment: @Haris You're right.